# Get size of text in div, problems in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I've got a text auto-resize script which resizes the text to fit the parent's size. The markup for this is

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="dynamic-text">Text to be resized</div>
</div>
```

I resize the text based on the height and width of the text and "parent".

What I can't seem to get is the width of the text in FireFox. I get the width by wrapping the text in  and doing a $("span").width(). This works perfectly in webkit but not in FF.

If the width of the text is greater than the parent, FF returns the width of the parent, which is probably the maximum size the span can take.

So question is, how do I get the width in FF (and IE also would help)

Comment: Qazi: Where is the span?

Comment: Problem solved guys. There was a problem in my javascript. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine for me .. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/T78gF/

I get the width of the span (*which i have included in the `.dynamic-text` div, with `$('.dynamic-text span').width();`

Are you trying to get the width of the text if it had not word-wrapped ?